# In mpld3 how to make red line draggable?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, mpld3

I am trying to drag red vertical line in vertical direction towards right and left side using mouse pointer and on release I want to print x-axes value.
I am not able to connect line_a with DragPlugin class.
I followed https://mpld3.github.io/examples/drag_points.html this code as a reference.

```
"""
Draggable Points Example
========================
This example shows how a D3 plugin can be created to make plot elements
draggable.  A stopPropagation command is used to allow the drag behavior
and pan/zoom behavior to work in tandem.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

import mpld3
from matplotlib import lines
from mpld3 import plugins, utils


class DragPlugin(plugins.PluginBase):
    JAVASCRIPT = r"""
    mpld3.register_plugin("drag", DragPlugin);
    DragPlugin.prototype = Object.create(mpld3.Plugin.prototype);
    DragPlugin.prototype.constructor = DragPlugin;
    DragPlugin.prototype.requiredProps = ["id"];
    DragPlugin.prototype.defaultProps = {}
    function DragPlugin(fig, props){
        mpld3.Plugin.call(this, fig, props);
        mpld3.insert_css("#" + fig.figid + " path.dragging",
                         {"fill-opacity": "1.0 !important",
                          "stroke-opacity": "1.0 !important"});
    };

    DragPlugin.prototype.draw = function(){
        var obj = mpld3.get_element(this.props.id);

        var drag = d3.drag()
            .on("drag", dragged)

        obj.elements()
           .data(obj.offsets)
           .style("cursor", "default")
           .call(drag);

        function dragstarted(d) {
          d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
          d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
        }

        function dragged(d, i) {
          d[0] = obj.ax.x.invert(d3.event.x);
          d[1] = obj.ax.y.invert(d3.event.y);
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + [d3.event.x,d3.event.y] + ")");
        }

        function dragended(d) {
          d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
        }
    }
    """

    def __init__(self, points):
        if isinstance(points, mpl.lines.Line2D):
            suffix = "pts"
        else:
            suffix = None

        self.dict_ = {"type": "drag",
                      "id": utils.get_id(points, suffix)}


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
np.random.seed(0)
points = ax.plot(np.random.normal(size=20),
                 np.random.normal(size=20), 'or', alpha=0.5,
                 markersize=50, markeredgewidth=1)
line_a = lines.Line2D((0.5, 0.5), (-3, 3),
                            pickradius=5,
                            color="r",
                            linewidth=2)
ax.add_line(line_a)
ax.set_title("Click and Drag", fontsize=18)

plugins.connect(fig, DragPlugin(points[0]))
plugins.connect(fig, DragPlugin(line_a))

mpld3.show()
```

**Please guide me how can I implement the code where user can drag red line marker vertically using mouse pointer and gets its position when mouse is released?**

[image]